# spring mvc, want to package classes(models etc), interceptors, controllers for re-use

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have some code that I am using in a Spring MVC application that I would like to re-use with my other applications.

The code is comprised of:

```
controllers
model classes
interceptor
service classes
```

There is also some mysql tables but I don't think I can package that up, I'll probably just create a script for that.

Is it possible to package the above code elements up (in a .jar) and then somehow just wire it up in the spring.xml file?

How can I do this?

I want to wire it up in a module way, not individually.

If there are more than 1 way to do this I'd love to know my options.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. 
Create separate project per module. Create build script. If you are using maven it is relatively simple. At least you can find a lot of examples to start from.
Your spring module can contain either classes and XML descriptors.

When you are developing your application create project for it and add your "spring modele" as a dependency. Now when you are writing your application level spring descriptors you can either use your module's classes and pre-defined descriptors.

Actually spring is modular itself. It consists of core and a lot of modules in our terms. Application programmers use these modules. It means that they can also create their own reusable modules.

Comment: but how do I do it? how do I wire it in a new project? I'm using maven, but not looking for a maven specific way.  The issue is, how do I wire my custom module, and how will it then integrate the interceptor?

Answer (score 0):

Create a single Jar for all compiled modules like this..

```
first create a menifest file named menifest.MF and then execute command..

>jar cmf menifest.MF my_modules.jar *.class
```

Now use my_modules.jar in classpath of your another project and use beans as you go usually